# How to add a PPA which does not include my Ubuntu distribution?

Tags: apt, ppa

I am trying to add `ppa:stevedh/smap` to my repository with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stevedh/smap
```

It gets added. When i sudo do `apt-get update` I recieve the following message:

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/stevedh/smap/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404 Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/stevedh/smap/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
404 Not Found
```

When I browse http://ppa.launchpad.net/stevedh/smap/ubuntu/dists there are 3 dists available:

- jaunty
- oneiric
- precise

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, open the file that contains the name of the PPA in a text editor. The name will be something like `stevedh-smap-trusty.list`. Then, after the URL on the first line and the second line, change `trusty` to `precise` (since that's the most recent Ubuntu version supported by the PPA). For example:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stevedh/smap/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stevedh/smap/ubuntu precise main
```

Save the file and run `sudo apt-get update`.

That being said, note that because of library updates and packaging changes between Precise and Trusty, there is no guarantee that you'll be able to install the software from that PPA, much less run it.